# How to append elements to String[][]?

Tags: java

I have the following:

```
   String[][] content = {
            {"c","d", "2"},
            {"e","f", "3"},
            {"g","h", "4"},
            {"i","j", "5"}} ;
```

What can I do to add some 1x3 elements to the already existing ones?

Comment: 2D arrays are fixed length. You can't append elements to them. The best option (that stays with 2D arrays) is to create a new array of a larger size that can hold the current values and the new values. Then add all the values to it.

Comment: Yash Capoor is right. If this method is too cumbersome, you'd probably better switch to `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: @uksz Please check my answer

Comment: If you don't have very, very strict guidelines for memory use and performance, you will be much better off avoiding arrays, and using some kind of collection instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] content = {
                {"c","d", "2"},
                {"e","f", "3"},
                {"g","h", "4"},
                {"i","j", "5"}};

        String[][] newContent = {{"p","a", "3"}};

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(append(content, newContent)));
    }

    public static String[][] append(String[][] a, String[][] b) {
        String[][] result = new String[a.length + b.length][];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, a.length, b.length);
        return result;
    }
```

**Output**

```
[[c, d, 2], [e, f, 3], [g, h, 4], [i, j, 5], [p, a, 3]]
```

**Another Input**

```
String[][] content = {
                {"c","d", "2"},
                {"S","2"},
                {"i","j", "5"},{"p","1"}};

String[][] newContent = {{"p","a", "3"},{"k","3"}};
```

**Output**

```
[[c, d, 2], [S, 2], [i, j, 5], [p, 1], [p, a, 3], [k, 3]]
```

Comment: @uksz if my answer is helpful then please upvote and accept my answer , thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

This is cumbersome, involving creating a copy of the entire array, hence not something to do regularly:

```
String[][] content = {
        {"c","d", "2"},
        {"e","f", "3"},
        {"g","h", "4"},
        {"i","j", "5"}};
content = Arrays.copyOf(content, content.length + 1);
content[content.length - 1] = new String[] { "k", "l", "6" };
```

However you can work with List:

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(list, content);
list.add(new String[] { "k", "l", "6" });
```

With operations like:

```
String[] row = list.remove(2);
list.get(1)[3]; // Getting
list.add(0, row); // Adding at an index
```

Comment: Hello sir , Please check my answer that is very sort and sweet :)

Comment: @ParthSolanki nice; you do not need to things like import and class ;)

Comment: Okay sir , thanks for advice I will update my answer .